# Looking for the Lowest and the Highest column in a List with 3 columns, PYTHON

Tags: python

How can I found the **third** column of a list where the **first** column is the **lowest** value **and** the **second** column is the **highest** value?

This is the example of the list.

```
[(12, 17, 'WOLNEY DE AZEVEDO PERRUCHO JÚNIOR'), 
 (8, 15, 'WSTANIA BARBOSA GONÇALVES'), 
 (6, 13, 'WYCLIFFE DE MELO COUTO'),
 (6, 16, 'WYLDENSOR MARTINS SOARES'), 
 (4, 8, 'XERXES GUSMÃO'), 
 (7, 17, 'XISTO ALBARELLI RANGEL NETO'), 
 (8, 5, 'YANNICK CAUBET'), 
 (7, 17, 'YASMIN ALINE PIOVESAN BURIN'), 
 (7, 16, 'YEDA MARIA MORALES SÁNCHEZ'), 
 (6, 12, 'YEDA MONTEIRO ATHIAS'), 
 (18, 22, 'YEDDA CHRISTINA CHING-SAN FILIZZOLA ASSUNÇÃO'), 
 (6, 16, 'YGOR VIEIRA DE FIGUEIRÊDO'), 
 (6, 5, 'YONG SUK CHOI'), 
 (8, 11, 'YURI DANTAS DE SANTANA'),
 (5, 12, 'YURI RAMALHO DANTAS'), 
 (8, 11, 'ZANDER BARBOSA DALCIN'), 
 (7, 12, 'ZANDER VIEIRA PACHECO'), 
 (6, 18, 'ZARY DE OLIVEIRA COSTA FILHO'), 
 (8, 14, 'ZELAIDE DE SOUZA PHILIPPI')]
```

Comment: This isn't a site for free programmers or where you can find people to do your homework.  Take a shot at this yourself, and show us what you've tried. - I'm not sure your statement of the question is even well defined.  Show us what output you expect, and what output or error you're getting, along with your code

Comment: You could ask for a general plan of attack if you really can't even get started.  But if you can't get started yourself, what is the purpose here?

Comment: This kind of comments it isn't necessary, if I am asking about that, is because I am having problems to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps compute the minimum of the first column, the maximum of the second, and then search for a row that matches that criteria:

```
minFirst = min(x[0] for x in data)
maxSecond = max(x[1] for x in data)
selected = next((x[2] for x in data if x[0] == minFirst and x[1] == maxSecond), None)
```

Comment: Thank you man! I am new In Python , that why I am ask this simple question, maybe I need to learn search better in the documentations, But it was exactly what I Want.